# Magento 2 Additional step between shipping and payment in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, requirejs, mixins

I created a custom step login in checkout which being my first step I used the below mixins:

In `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
'config': {
    'mixins': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
            'MyVendor_Customcheckout/js/view/shipping-payment-mixin': true
        },
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment': {
            'MyVendor_Customcheckout/js/view/shipping-payment-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
};
```

and in `shipping-payment-mixin.js`:

```
define(
[
'ko'
], 
 function (ko) {
 'use strict';

var mixin = {

    initialize: function () {

// this.isVisible variable is used by Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment. this variable is missing from the sample code.
        this.isVisible = ko.observable(false);

// this.visible variable is used by Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipment.
        this.visible = ko.observable(false);
        this._super();
        return this;
    }
};

return function (target) {
    return target.extend(mixin);
};
}
);
```

Now I created another step say scheduling which is an additional step between shipping and payment.

I haven't created any mixin for this yet but on page load, my shipping and scheduling form shows on the same page.

Is it an issue related to mixin? Or is it some other issue? How do I create a mixin for this?